# Can we store context of a fragment in class which is initialized inside that fragment. Will the fragment be destroyed?

Tags: android

I am creating a Datastore which requires context of fragment.

```
class LayoutSettingDataStore(private val context : Context) {}
```

Can I store it as a member variable or should I use it parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

That type of context storage would not allow reliable memory management.

Сareless use of context can lead to memory leaks. I think the best solution is to use the context as a method parameter.